# Removing strings from data.table based on partial match with regex in R

Tags: r, string, gsub

I am looking to remove strings across my data.table based on a partial match:

```
$$ER
```

Since these strings differ across the entire table, and my table is reasonably large, efficiency and speed is preferred. I have tried data.table's %like% but this is way too inefficient. gsub should do fine but I have an issue referencing the "$$" in the "$$ER".

```
structure(list(Country = c("NL", "NL", "NL", "NL", "DE", "DE", 
"DE", "GB", "GB"), Value1 = c("$$ER: Data not found", NA, NA, 
NA, "$$ERROR: NOT AVAILABLE", NA, NA, "3", "4"), Value2 = c("$$ER: Data not found", 
NA, NA, NA, "$$ERROR: NOT AVAILABLE", NA, NA, "3", "4"), Value3 = c(10, 
15, 12, 9, 8, 20, 23, 3, 4)), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
-9L))

  Country                 Value1                 Value2 Value3
1      NL   $$ER: Data not found   $$ER: Data not found     10
2      NL                   <NA>                   <NA>     15
3      NL                   <NA>                   <NA>     12
4      NL                   <NA>                   <NA>      9
5      DE $$ERROR: NOT AVAILABLE $$ERROR: NOT AVAILABLE      8
6      DE                   <NA>                   <NA>     20
7      DE                   <NA>                   <NA>     23
8      GB                      5                      6      3
9      GB                      6                      8      4
```

Desired output:

```
  Country Value1 Value2 Value3
1      NL     NA     NA     10
2      NL     NA     NA     15
3      NL     NA     NA     12
4      NL     NA     NA      9
5      DE     NA     NA      8
6      DE     NA     NA     20
7      DE     NA     NA     23
8      GB      5      6      3
9      GB      6      8      4
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

An alternative would be to use `grepl`:

```
df[apply(df, 2, function(i) grepl('$$ER', i, fixed = T))] <- NA
```

which would yield the following:

```
# Country Value1 Value2 Value3
# 1      NL   <NA>   <NA>     10
# 2      NL   <NA>   <NA>     15
# 3      NL   <NA>   <NA>     12
# 4      NL   <NA>   <NA>      9
# 5      DE   <NA>   <NA>      8
# 6      DE   <NA>   <NA>     20
# 7      DE   <NA>   <NA>     23
# 8      GB      3      3      3
# 9      GB      4      4      4
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `startsWith` in `sapply` testing for `$$ER`.

```
D[2:3][sapply(D[2:3], startsWith, "$$ER")] <- NA
D
#  Country Value1 Value2 Value3
#1      NL   <NA>   <NA>     10
#2      NL   <NA>   <NA>     15
#3      NL   <NA>   <NA>     12
#4      NL   <NA>   <NA>      9
#5      DE   <NA>   <NA>      8
#6      DE   <NA>   <NA>     20
#7      DE   <NA>   <NA>     23
#8      GB      3      3      3
#9      GB      4      4      4
```

But maybe you want to use `as.numeric`:

```
D[2:3] <- sapply(D[2:3], as.numeric)
D
#  Country Value1 Value2 Value3
#1      NL     NA     NA     10
#2      NL     NA     NA     15
#3      NL     NA     NA     12
#4      NL     NA     NA      9
#5      DE     NA     NA      8
#6      DE     NA     NA     20
#7      DE     NA     NA     23
#8      GB      3      3      3
#9      GB      4      4      4
```

Answer (score 0):

Using `data.table` -

```
library(data.table)

setDT(df)[, (2:3) := lapply(.SD, function(x) 
    as.numeric(replace(x, grepl('$$ER', x, fixed = TRUE), NA))), .SDcols = 2:3]
df

#   Country Value1 Value2 Value3
#1:      NL     NA     NA     10
#2:      NL     NA     NA     15
#3:      NL     NA     NA     12
#4:      NL     NA     NA      9
#5:      DE     NA     NA      8
#6:      DE     NA     NA     20
#7:      DE     NA     NA     23
#8:      GB      3      3      3
#9:      GB      4      4      4
```